# Apache RewriteEngine affect Tomcat access

Tags: tomcat, apache2

There is the problem,

I have configured htaccess to rewrite all access for http to https, its ok.
But i need make a exception for Tomcat on 8080 port.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "!^8080$"
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,NC,R]

# Send / to /roundcube.
RewriteRule ^/?$ /roundcube [L]
```

currently when accessing http mydomain.com:8080 am redirected to https mydomain.com:8080 (causing problems with SSL). I need only to be ignored if you use port 8080 by accessing normally http mydomain.com:8080.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with new subdomain and new config for tomcat on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName tomcat.mydomain.com

        ServerAdmin postmaster@mydomain.com
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tomcat.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:8080%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

For me a new subdomain exclusive for tomcat was even better.